# Why this code works fine? (vector.clear(), vector<vector<int> >)

Tags: c++, memory, vector

Here's a snippet of a code I submitted. It worked but it made me think how exactly `clear()` works for a vector.

```
vector<vector<int> > result;
vector<int> temp;
temp.push_back(1);
temp.push_back(2);
result.push_back(temp);
temp.clear();
temp.push_back(3);
temp.push_back(4);
result.push_back(temp);

//print result vector here.
```

How come the result vector is `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`.

Here's what [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/clear) has to say about `vector.clear()`:

> Removes all elements from the container. Invalidates any references,
>   pointers, or iterators referring to contained elements. May invalidate
>   any past-the-end iterators.   Leaves the capacity() of the vector
>   unchanged.

I suspect that this behavior should not be relied upon.

Should clearing the temp vector not destroy the contents? Also, the description on `cppreference` makes me feel like inserting `3` and `4` will cause them to overwrite `1` and `2` since the `temp` vector was not allocated any new memory?

Here's the code on ideone: https://ideone.com/Onwlro

Comment: The temp is copyed into the result. Yes, temp will be cleared and the elems will be deleted, but the copys in result won't be deleted.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. That is what appeared to me in the first look. But I'm under the impression that `push_back` should only copy a pointer reference of `temp` vector for **non-primitive** data types. Can you give some reference that assures data is copied element by element?

Comment: www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`push_back` takes a reference but it copies the passed value in the function.  From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

> `void push_back( const T& value );(1)`
>
> `void push_back( T&& value );(2)   (since C++11)`
>
> Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
>
> 1) The new element is initialized as a copy of value.
>
> 2) value is moved into the new element.

Since it is making a copy of the vector the vectors in `result` will not be changed when you call `temp.clear()`

Comment: Worth pointing out that this also depends on the object being pushed back having implemented the copy or move constructors and the assignment or move operators.